# jQuery unbind listener

Tags: events, triggers, event-handling, jquery

I have issue to unbind one listeners that listen one of shared emitter:

```
// this is emitter. Fire always in a.b.c namespace but with different parameters 
$(document).trigger("a.b.c", {
    p: 1,
    p2: ...

});

// listener 1
$(document).bind("a.b.c", function(e, object) {
    if (object.myParam) {
        ....
    }
});

// listener 2
$(document).bind("a.b.c", function(e, object) {
    if (object.anotherParam) {
        ....
    }
});
```

How to unbind listener 2, so listeners 1 still continue work?

Comment: how did you get to that situation. there must be a design flaw in your design

Comment: could you please explain why it's flaw? I need the same namespace but with different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

```
// this is emitter. Fire always in a.b.c namespace but with different parameters 
$(document).trigger("a.b.c", {
    p: 1,
    p2: ...

});

// listener 1
$(document).bind("a.b.c.listener1", function(e, object) {
    if (object.myParam) {
        ....
    }
});

// listener 2
$(document).bind("a.b.c.listener2", function(e, object) {
    if (object.anotherParam) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Now trigging `a.b.c` will trigger with `listener1` and `listener2`.
And to unbind - just unbind with specific listener, like:

```
$(document).unbind("a.b.c.listener1");
```

In that case `listener2` will be preserved, and will be able to invoked via namespace `a.b.c`

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference to the handler so that you can later [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it:

```
var listener = function(e, object) {
    if (object.anotherParam) {
        ....
    }
};


$(document).bind("a.b.c", listener);

// sometime later:
$(document).unbind("a.b.c", listener);
```